# Platform.runLater

Tags: java, javafx

Я хочу открыть новое окно в контроллере другого окна через другой класс.
На пример вот функция которая находится в контроллере:

```
public void openNewScene(String Window)  {
        search.setVisible(false);
        playButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(Window));
        Const.gameController = (GameController) loader.getController();
        try {
            loader.load();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        final Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });
        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Она вызывается в другом классе(мини-сервере) когда туда посылается опред. сигнал:

```
  if (type == MessageTypes.SEARCH_REPLY) {
     Const.menuController.openNewScene("/Main/GameWindow/GameWindow.fxml");
  }
```

Но после этого я получаю исключение

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1185)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.hide(Window.java:1211)
    at Main.Menu.MenuController.openNewScene(MenuController.java:207)
    at Main.ClientServer.run(ClientServer.java:40)
```

Это означает что я хочу обраться к FX объекту не через FX поток и нужно добавить
Platform.runLater, НО я не понимаю куда. Ведь куда бы я не сунул везде ошибка о том что это не подходит..

Comment: А можешь добавить пример, где ты добавил `Platform.runLater` и оно завалилось? По идее, `Platform.runLater(() -> Const.menuController.openNewScene("/Main/GameWindow/GameWindow.fxml"))` можно поместить в любое место и этого будет достаточно.

Comment: В твоём случае, должно быть что-то вроде этого: 
`
  if (type == MessageTypes.SEARCH_REPLY) {
     Platform.runLater(() ->Const.menuController.openNewScene("/Main/GameWindow/GameWindow.fxml"));
  }
`

Comment: Если ошибка возникает при перетягивании объекта, тогда проблема в `root.setOnMousePressed`. Содержимое листенера оберните в `Platform.runLater`

Comment: Да, это действительно сработало, а не подскажите, почему это работает через лямбду, а без нее, что то вроде: Platform.runLater(Const.menuController.openNewScene("/Main/GameWindow/GameWindow.fxml")); не робит

Comment: Потому что добавляя лямбду, ты говоришь: "вот функция/задача, выполни её в главном потоке", а без лямбды ты просто выполняешь эту функцию, т.е. функция выполняется во вспомогательном потоке.